# table is not resizable in tinyMCE 4 in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

Table properties are not worked in tinyMCE 4 inline editors, I tried to set the default style for table

```
table_default_styles: {
            width: '50%'
        },
```

It's not applied and the table resizable also not working, though I used every property

```
table_column_resizing: 'resizetable',
```

the table looks like this,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `table_column_resizing` option was added to TinyMCE 5.5 so that is not a valid configuration option for TinyMCE 4:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/release-notes/release-notes55/#newtable_column_resizingoptionforcontrollingtablecolumnresizing

I would note that the option does not determine **if** the table is resizable but rather the behavior that happens **when** a table is resized.

When I add a table to TinyMCE using your `table_default_styles` configuration option I get this HTML:

```
<table style="width: 50%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td style="width: 48.7125%;">&nbsp;</td>
  <td style="width: 48.7996%;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="width: 48.7125%;">&nbsp;</td>
  <td style="width: 48.7996%;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

...which takes up half of the editor as I would expect.  Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle demonstrating this:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/L4haab

I have attached screenshots of the latest TinyMCE 5 and TinyMCE 4 - neither of which show the outcome you have in your screenshot.

**TinyMCE 5**
[image]

**TinyMCE 4**
[image]

***Note**: TinyMCE 4 is no longer a supported/developed version of TinyMCE so you would likely benefit from moving to TinyMCE 5 as that version is still under active development.*

Comment: Thanks, could you please try this with inline editor?

Comment: Since really Still I have this issue , though I removed that `table_column_resizing `

Comment: Nothing changes regarding the table's size or layout if I switch to using inline mode:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/L4haab/2